# If else statement (basic)

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Need help to create If else statement. If sum all field 9 = sum all field 10, delete field 10 else highlight field 10 entire column.
Note: Field 9 is Column "I", Field 10 is Column "J"

```
Sub Macro1()

        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=9, Criteria1:="<>"
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=10, Criteria1:="<>"

 'IF Formula
IF  Activesheet.Range ("I") = Activesheet.Range ("J"),     
        Columns("J:J").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Else 
     Do nothing
 'If Formula ends
    End Sub
```

Comment: You write "If sum all field 9 = sum all field 10"  so you need  IF application.worksheetfunction.sum("I:I") = application.worksheetfunction.sum("J:J") then

Comment: Should be THEN instead of a comma at the end of your line starting IF

Answer (score 1):

A few mistakes in your code:

**The basics of IF:**

You need to write

```
If *Condition* Then
*Do smth*
Else 
*Do Smth*
End If
```

You can take the Else away if you don't do anything.

**Sum in a filter:**

As Harassed Dad wrote in his comment:
 The condition should be written like this :

```
Application.worksheetfunction.sum("I:I") = Application.worksheetfunction.sum("J:J")
```

**Do not use Select:**

Using select makes your code slow and harder to read. The first thing to optimize is to avoid using select. In this link you will find a great answer to avoid using Select: 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Finally, your code should look rather like this:

```
Sub Macro1()

 ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=9, Criteria1:="<>"
 ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=10, Criteria1:="<>"

 'IF Formula
     IF  Application.worksheetfunction.sum(Range("I:I").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) = _
Application.worksheetfunction.sum(Range("J:J").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) Then    
            Columns("J:J").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft 'instead of .Select and Selection.
         End If
     'If Formula ends
    End Sub
```

Comment: I tried input the code, it prompt run-time error '1004': Unable to get the Sum property of the WorksheetFunction Class.

Comment: Because Sum("A:A") doesn t work. You need to enter a range inside. I corrected it sorry. Now I tested the code, it should work

Comment: It works as per what I needed. Really appreciate your assistance on this. Have a great day ahead.